# Problems connecting to a MariaDB server: java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: mysql, spring, jdbc, mariadb

I am trying to connect a Spring Boot Application to my MariaDB server which is up and running. I am getting the following error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource 
...
Caused by: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Now I've seen that similar questions have been asked on Stackoverflow before, and I tried the most common approaches, like granting all privileges:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '%password%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

And removing the `password` for the root user:

```
SET PASSWORD FOR root@localhost=PASSWORD('');
```

None of these approaches worked so far. I cannot really change the .properties file, but from what I can see a password is generated, encrypted and stored every time the application runs:

```
connection.driver_class = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
connection.url = jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/local02?useSSL=true
connection.username = root
connection.password = ../../config/local/dbkey.txt
connection.pool_size = 200
```

It's important to highlight that I am experiencing this problem just on MacOS, on Windows (same files, same DB, same IDE) doesn't arise.

Is there anything else I can try?

Answer (score -2):

As far as I know Spring does not allow to use the root user of mariaDB. You must create a new user and grant priviledges.

Comment: I tried creating a new user, same problem.

Comment: You can use any user you want. Root, admin, foo, bar... Spring doesn't prevent anything.